# Shell API to copy all files in a folder?

Tags: shell, winapi, lazarus, freepascal

I am using FreePascal/Lazarus, and I am trying to find the correct ShlObj/ShellApi calls to copy all files from a Device's DCIM Folder (i.e. a Camera) to another folder on the filesystem.

Here is the code to select to select the device:

```
r:=  ShlObj.SHBrowseForFolder(x);
```

But from, there all I have is r, which is a `LPITEMIDLIST` variable.

Does anyone know the correct code to copy all files inside the Device's DCIM Folder 'r', to a destination folder (i.e. strDest)?

Note: I must use the ShellApi/ShlObj interface to do the copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the PIDL specifies an item that is part of the file system, but I believe that is what you intend since you go on to say "copy all files". In which case, call [`SHGetPathFromIDList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762194.aspx) to obtain the file system path from the PIDL, and then call [`SHFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) to copy the files.

If you want to perform copying at the shell level, and not be restricted to files, then it's a little more complex. Probably the simplest will be to use [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx), specifically the `CopyItem` and `CopyItems` methods. You'll need to be able to go from a PIDL to an `IShellItem` which can be done with [`SHCreateItemFromIDList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762133.aspx).

Comment: Oh sorry, I intend to copy files on a Device such as a Digital Camera. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please can you fix the question to make it clear what you actually want.

Comment: Anyway, I added some more text. Do you have any knowledge at all of shell programming, and the interfaces that are used, PIDLs, etc.?

Comment: I think you'll need to build up your knowledge quite slowly. It will take a bit of getting used to.

Comment: I definitely will! One thing, Lazarus/FP doesn't have SHCreateItemFromIDList defined in ShlObj/ShellApi, do I have to manually declare it via extern?

Comment: Yeah, here's mine from my Delphi code:  `function SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl: PItemIDList; const riid: TIID; out pv): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll';`

Comment: @user1924308: The way to say *"You're a champ!"* on stackoverflow, is to upvote an answer that you found useful.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Would you have an idea for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277997/copy-file-with-windows-using-shell-api-no-such-interface-supported? In this context, I don't know why `CopyItem` doesn't work.