# Copy file with Windows using Shell API CopyItem: "No such interface supported" for non-drive-letter paths like Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg

Tags: python, windows, shell, winapi, pywin32

I'm using Windows Shell API [`IFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) to copy files from a phone (connected on USB) to the PC. It would be impossible with usual file-based copy functions (`os` or `shutil`), because it has no driver letter. Thus, I'm using:

```
import pythoncom
from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon

fo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL, shell.IID_IFileOperation)

src = shell.SHCreateShellItem(...)     # see last note below
dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(path, None, shell.IID_IShellItem)
                                     # these objects are well created
                                     # e.g. <PyIShellFolder at 0x0000000002A6AB50 with obj at 0x0000000002ADA270>

fo.CopyItem(src, dst)     # also tested: fo.CopyItem(src, dst_folder, filename), fo.CopyItem(src, dst_folder, None, None) etc.

fo.PerformOperations()    # error during this line
```

Report:

- standard paths like `C:\ABC\DEF\test.txt`: it works on both Win7 and Win10
- paths like `This PC\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg`: it works on Win10
- paths like `Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg`: **it fails on Win7** with the following error (note that `"This PC"` is named `"Computer"` on Win7).

Error:

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported', None, None)

How to make this code work on Windows 7? (I need to still support this platform)

Notes:

- linked with [Shell API to copy all files in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594470/shell-api-to-copy-all-files-in-a-folder) -(which advises to use `IFileOperation` and `CopyFile`) but not a duplicate.
- also linked with https://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/tshONvOX/ifileoperation-performoperations-returns-e-nointerface.
- about Windows version: it seemed that [`IFileOperation::CopyItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-copyitem) was supported since Windows Vista, see linked documentation
- @SimonMourier: I use `SHCreateShellItem` to create `src` because I am walking in a directory tree recursively:

  ```
  for f in folder.EnumObjects(0, shellcon.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS):
      srcfolder = shell.SHGetIDListFromObject(folder)
      src = shell.SHCreateShellItem(srcfolder, None, f)
      ...
  ```

  Also, I didn't use `shell.SHParseDisplayName` or `shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName` because it doesn't work on Win7 for paths like `Computer\MyPhone\Card\myfiles\test.txt`, see comments in [How to use SHCreateItemFromParsingName with names from the shell namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966489/how-to-use-shcreateitemfromparsingname-with-names-from-the-shell-namespace)

Comment: If the phone is connected as a USB storage device (which you need to pick on the phone when you connect it), it will absolutely have a drive letter.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Most phones don't connect as "USB Mass Storage" anymore (newest Android, iPhone, etc.). Thus they don't have a drive letter.

Comment: Code works fine with two paths created from SHCreateItemFromParsingName. What do you do exactly with SHCreateShellItem? please post some real code.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your comment. I edited the question: the last note bullet point explains why I'm using `SHCreateShellItem`. Note2: it works fine on Win10, in fact the problem ony happens on Win7 (which I still need to support). It seemed to me it was supported since Windows Vista: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-copyitem

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/tshONvOX/ifileoperation-performoperations-returns-e-nointerface

Comment: @Stuntman11, Yes, I found the same (point #2 in my "Notes")

Comment: This sample code works fine for me: https://pastebin.com/raw/P6HjMPx2

Comment: @SimonMourier On Win10, yes, but also on Win7?

Comment: @SimonMourier For me, it does work on Win10 but doesn't work on Win7.

Comment: Can you make the copy using Windows UI? If yes, it should work, but how it can be programmed depends precisely on the namespace extension you're using (IPhone, standard windows, custom, etc.). I only have Win7 in a virtual machine w/o phone so I can't test this.

Comment: Yes I can copy with Windows UI @SimonMourier. It's a standard (non-custom) Windows 7. I tried with both Android and iPhone, it doesn't work on Win7, but it works on Win10. It seems that Win7 doesn't implement `CopyItem` interface for non-drive-letter paths.

Comment: It's probably not a CopyItem issue, but more an lack of support of required interfaces that CopyItem uses in the code that handles that hierarchy in Explorer (a namespace extension implementing IShellFolder). I'll try to see if I can reproduce with Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to reproduce on Windows 7, and indeed, the WPD namespace extension (wpdshext.dll) doesn't support what's needed for IFileOperation (IShellItem.BindToHandler basically always fails on IStream, IStorage, ITransferMedium, etc). What you can do is call ParseDisplayName("...path...") on the root IShellFolder to get file path pidl, and then BindToObject(pidl) for IStream. Then you can copy the given stream. I think that's what Windows 7 does in this case. I can work a bit more if you want this in python.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for reproducing the error! Oh yes I would be highly interested, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code that supports Windows 10 and Windows 7, however not in the same manner.

The WPDShext.dll component shipped in Windows which is reponsible for handling the [portable devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windows-portable-devices) hierarchy is more limited in Windows 7 than in Window 10. It does not support interfaces such as `IStream` or `IStorage` from an [IShellItem::BindToHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler) implementation, which is probably what `IFileOperation` tries to do.

All it seems it can do is support an [IStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) when requested through its root folder's [IShellFolder::BindToObject method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-bindtoobject) implementation.

```
import pythoncom
import platform
from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon
from win32com import storagecon

# this points to my IPhone's root, adapt to your code or enumerate from root
folderPath = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\\\\?\\usb#vid_05ac&pid_12a8&mi_00#6&211e6304&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}"

# this relative path points to some image in that IPhone (same path as shown in Explorer)
itemPath = "Internal Storage\\DCIM\\202308__\\IMG_2047.JPG"

# get the root folder (IPhone, etc.)
folderItem = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(folderPath, None, shell.IID_IShellItem)

if (int(platform.release()) < 8): # release is hopefully reliable enough for Windows 7 detection...

    # get WPDShext.dll's namespace extension IShellFolder implementation
    folder = folderItem.BindToHandler(None, shell.BHID_SFObject, shell.IID_IShellFolder)

    # get the relative child item
    ret = folder.ParseDisplayName(None, None, itemPath, 0)

    # get the item's stream using the relative pidl, from IShellFolder
    inputStream = folder.BindToObject(ret[1], None, pythoncom.IID_IStream)

    # get its size, don't ask for name in this code (avoid releasing mem)
    inputStat = inputStream.Stat(1) # STATFLAG_NONAME

    # open a file for writing & copy from input to output
    outputStream = shell.SHCreateStreamOnFileEx("c:\\temp\\IMG_2047.JPG", storagecon.STGM_CREATE | storagecon.STGM_WRITE, 0, True, None)
    inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream, inputStat[2])

else:

    src = shell.SHCreateItemFromRelativeName(folderItem, itemPath, None, shell.IID_IShellItem)
    dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName("c:\\temp", None, shell.IID_IShellItem)
                                         
    fo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL, shell.IID_IFileOperation)
    fo.CopyItem(src, dst)
    fo.PerformOperations()
```

Note you can also use the [WPD API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/wpd-application-programming-interface) if you want but 1) it's not super easy to use and 2) not sure it's easy to do in python.

Here is some extra sample code that allows you to determine what to use for the `folderPath` variable used above:

```
import pythoncom
from win32comext.shell import shell

desktopItem = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName("", None, shell.IID_IShellItem)
for item in desktopItem.BindToHandler(None, shell.BHID_EnumItems, shell.IID_IEnumShellItems):
    print(item.GetDisplayName(0) + " parsing name: " + item.GetDisplayName(0x80018001)) # SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING
```

It will display something like this:

```
Downloads parsing name: ::{088E3905-0323-4B02-9826-5D99428E115F}
3D Objects parsing name: ::{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}
Pictures parsing name: ::{24AD3AD4-A569-4530-98E1-AB02F9417AA8}
Music parsing name: ::{3DFDF296-DBEC-4FB4-81D1-6A3438BCF4DE}
Desktop parsing name: ::{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
Documents parsing name: ::{D3162B92-9365-467A-956B-92703ACA08AF}
Videos parsing name: ::{F86FA3AB-70D2-4FC7-9C99-FCBF05467F3A}
Apple iPhone parsing name: \\?\usb#vid_05ac&pid_12a8&mi_00#6&211e6304&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}
Local Disk (C:) parsing name: C:
DATA (D:) parsing name: D:
```

And `{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` is `CLSID_MyComputer` (aka "This PC" or "Computer" or whatever in localized Windows version)

Comment: Thanks! It still bugs for me... How do you find `folderPath = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D...`? I have something very similar to you and `print(folderItem)` seems to confirm it's ok, but I am stuck at line `ret = folder.ParseDisplayName(None, None, itemPath, 0)` with `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024894, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, None)`

Comment: In order to debug it, how can I test with the input file given by a single string (it's easy to get it by doing CTRL+C on the source file, than CTRL+V in the Explorer adress bar => then I can copy paste this address elsewhere). Something like `inputFile_full_path = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860#5200864cbc37657b#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{20002,SECZ9519043CHOHB01,127815548928}\{CLASS1}\{CLASS2}\{CLASS3}"`. How to use this in the Win7 case?

Comment: I've added a tool to get parsing names. You cannot use just one big string to get to an item deep in the WPD hierarchy. You must get the "phone folder" first.

Comment: Thanks again @SimonMourier! Now I can find the right path, but sometimes it gets stuck at step `ret = folder.ParseDisplayName(None, None, itemPath, 0)`. Sometimes it even freezes the Windows Explorer UI. Once or twice it worked. And after playing with all API functions, I even had a very strange behaviour : my Phone's root folder revealed, instead of `DCIM` and a few other folders, hundreds of old photos (2 years ago) that should have been deleted since a long time! So I guess the handling on Win7 is rather erratic. And also on the phone, where did all these files come from ? Maybe thumbnails?

Comment: It depends on lots of things (telephone, performance, usb, etc.), but I don't have such problems with Windows 7 (64b) and an old IPhone 6S.